# Inheritance of non-private fields if "not hidden by a declaration in the class"

Tags: java, inheritance, field, language-specifications

This phrase form the Java 11 Language Specification (8.3 Field Declarations) is not clear for me

> A class inherits from its direct superclass and direct superinterfaces
>   all the nonprivate fields of the superclass and superinterfaces that
>   are both accessible (§6.6) to code in the class and **not hidden by a
>   declaration in the class**.

That is it is not clear if a name of the superclass is hidden by a declaration in the class does it mean that nonprivate fields are not inherited?

The part of the phrase "and not hidden by a declaration in the class" is confusing.

Comment: Maybe this has to do with masking / shadowing? If your sublcass declares a field or local variable with the same name as the one in the superclass, java prioritizes the most local definition by default, and you therefore "lose access" to the original.

Comment: @AustinSchäfer I think that inheritance and hiding are two different things.

Comment: I would try a small example: create a super class with `String s = "s"` and subclass it with `String s = "t"`, and see which value it gives when you print to console. And they may be two different things, but their interplay could be why this ends up being mentioned. If my example doesn't work, then I'm wrong and it isn't the problem.

Comment: @AustinSchäfer It is obvious that s of the subclass will be accessed. But how is it related to the phrase?

Comment: If the subclass variable masks the superclass variable, then it was "hidden by a declaration in the class (the subclass)."

Comment: @AustinSchäfer I agree with this but it does not mean that  nonprivate fields are not inherited.

Comment: Ok, no problem; it was only the first thing which came to my mind.

Answer (score -1):

Oh, I have understood the phrase. The problem is that English is not my native language.

The phrase means that if a field of the supertclass or a superinterface is for example hidden by a declaration of the subclass then according to the Java Specification that field is not inherited. Though in my opinion it looks strange.

But to prove my conclusion I can cite a comment for the example *Example 8.3.1.1-2. Hiding of Class Variables*. There is written the following

> ...because the declaration of x in class Test hides the definition of
>   x in class Point, so class Test does not inherit the field x from its
>   superclass Point.

Nevertheless the subclass `Test` can access the hidden field of the class `Point`. So the statement that the class `Test` does not inherit the field `x` looks strange for example for a C++ programmer.:)

Comment: It looks strange how? If it's hidden, how do you think it should appear in the subclass?

Comment: @user207421 I pointed out that it looks strange for a C++ programmer. In C++ even if a member of a base class is hiden by a member of a derived class nevertheless the data member of the base class is inherited by the derived class.

Comment: @user207421 It seems you never dealt with C++. Logically if a derived class has acces to members of the base class then it is obvious that the derived class inherits the members of the base class.

Comment: It seems, you are confusing “inheritance”, “accessibility”, and even “has storage per instance” here. A subclass may *access* a field even if it is not *inherited*, e.g. via `super.name`, but it’s also possible to access, e.g. a `public` field via `variable.name` from an entirely different context. Being able to access a variable does not prove that the variable has been inherited. Neither does the absence of a possibility to access a variable prove that the variable (and its per-instance *storage*) did not exist. Most notably, the never-inherited `private` variables do, of course, still exist